# The discord register system with Python gives an error "Invalid-response"

Tags: python, discord, captcha, hcaptcha

I am trying to create a discord register system via Python. But hCaptcha gives the "Invalid-response" error.

Is Discord the real cause of this problem or is there a different factor?

````
from anticaptchaofficial.hcaptchaproxyless import *
import requests
import config

solver = hCaptchaProxyless()
solver.set_verbose(1)
solver.set_key(config.KEY)
solver.set_website_url("https://discord.com/register")
solver.set_website_key("4c672d35-0701-42b2-88c3-78380b0db560")
solver.set_user_agent(config.MY_USER_AGENT)

solver.set_soft_id(0)

g_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution()
if g_response != 0:
    print("g-response: "+g_response)
else:
    print("task finished with error "+solver.error_code)

register_url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/register"
payload = {
    "fingerprint":"",
    "email":"@gmail.com",
    "username":"",
    "password":"",
    "invite":"null",
    "consent":"true",
    "date_of_birth":"1990-01-01",
    "gift_code_sku_id":"null",
    "captcha_key":g_response,
    "promotional_email_opt_in":"false"
    }
r = requests.post(register_url,json=payload)
print(r.text)```
````

Comment: Please provide the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this video to solve the Hcaptcha for Discord. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0ltHB75Rt0. Thanks to [Exordium](https://www.youtube.com/c/ExordiumYT) !!!
The Video describes a free and paid version. The free version, at least when I tested, did not work. You can use the paid version with your 2captcha or any captcha solver api key.

In my test I used Neocities as that has the captcha on the main page.
Here is my version of the app.js that works:

```js
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import RecaptchaPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha";
//import bypass from "./bypass/captchaBypasser.js";

puppeteer.use(
    RecaptchaPlugin({
        provider: {
            //fn: bypass,
            id:  '2captcha',
            token: 'your_2captcha_api_key',
        },
    })
);

puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async (browser) => {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://neocities.org/#new')
    console.log('Solving Captcha...')
    await page.solveRecaptchas()
    console.log('Solved Captcha')
})
```

If this works for you, please mark as an answer. Good Luck